# Trying to print res.locals variabe in view page(.hbs)

Tags: node.js, express

My controllers looks like this in usermains.js

```
var header = function (req, res, next) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.locals.title="helloooo";
res.write(loadView('headerpage'));
console.log(res.title);
next();
};
app.get('/log',header,values,renderBody);
```

Here is my loadview function

```
var loadView = function(name, locals) {
if(name=='main'){
console.log(path.join('views/layouts/'+name + '.hbs'));
var template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('views/layouts/'+name +'.hbs')).toString();
 }else{
console.log(path.join('views/'+name + '.hbs'));
var template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('views/'+name +  '.hbs')).toString();
}
return template;
};
```

And i am calling this on view page.

```
{{title}}
```

It is giving output as {{title}} on browser. How to get res.locals.title value on view page. Thanks!

Comment: You have to pass the variable to the view. Show us the `loadView` function.

Comment: @AndreyPopov: Please see my edit.

Comment: Well handlebars is a whole engine. You must use it in order to parse your templates. Right now you include them raw, so `{{title}}` will be rendered as `{{title}}`. You must use `compile` method on handlerbars and then execute it. Something like: `var html = handlebars.compile(fs.readFileSync(..).toString())(dataAvailableInView);` Where `dataAvailableInView` can be your `res.locals`, or whatever you need.

Comment: @AndreyPopov Please post as answer... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes.. Thanks again @AndreyPopov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Handlebars in order to first compile, and then execute the template, passing the appropriate data that you wish. Simply reading/loading the template will give you the raw data. Use something like (tweak it for your needs, this is only a sample):

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var rawTemplate = fs.readFileSync(path.join('views/'+name +  '.hbs')).toString();
var compiledTemplate = handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);
var result = compiledTemplate(dataPassedToTemplate);

res.write(result);
```